# Pycharm 2016.1.4 (newest) and Docker issue

Tags: docker, pycharm

I'm running the newest (at this point) version of pycharm with the newest docker plugin available for that version (which is 2.1.2, 2.2 isn't working and 2.3 is not supported).

The problem is I'm getting

```
Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter
         {"message":"starting container with HostConfig was deprecated since v1.10 and removed in v1.12"}
```

Error when trying to set up remote interpreter (this then goes in "invalid" state). My docker version is 1.11 (also used 1.12-rc). I assume it would have worked on 1.9.0 probably but this makes me unable to use new features of docker which is suprising because the 1.11 version is there for quite a long time... anyone having same problems? Is there a way around this? I mean having the newer docker and make it work with the newest pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PyCharm is attempting to use an API option that is deprecated in API version 1.24. See the [Docker source code here](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/f10085165a42dc93b6180e0e5478f71c1c614126/api/server/router/container/container_routes.go#L139-L153).

This issue can be resolved by either;

- Having PyCharm call a correct version of the API (for example, when using API version 1.23, the old behavior is still supported for backward compatibility)
- Make sure PyCharm is updated to no longer use the deprecated feature (i.e., set the container host-configuration when the container is *created*, not when it is *started*).